# How to sort by number, highest to lowest

Tags: python, list

Im a very basic coder trying to figure out how to sort this string into a list according to the number they are paired with. So far i have been able to split the string 'apples' but i cannot seem to have the sorted function return the number instead of the second character. How would i go about isolating the numbers in order to sort through them? It is important i use the lambda function that calls on the 'apple_sort' function.

```
apples = "McIntosh:3,Red Delicious:5,Fuji:8,Gala:6,Ambrosia:7,Honeycrisp:7.5,Granny Smith:1"

def apple_sort(apple):
  return apple[1]

def sort_csv(x):
  x = (x.split(","))
  return sorted(x, key=apple_sort)
print(sort_csv(apples))
```

My answer should print,

```
['Fuji:8', 'Honeycrisp:7.5', 'Ambrosia:7', 'Gala:6', 'Red Delicious:5', 'McIntosh:3', 'Granny Smith:1']
```

Comment: your solution is super close! In `apple_sort`, you just need to use `return apple.split(':')[1]` and add a `reverse=True` to your `sorted` call. If you want a one-liner, yatu's solution below is a good one.

Comment: @wpercy also the number string needs converting to a `float`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use [`sorted`](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/sorting.html) with the following `key` instead (note that the numerical strings must be cast to float) :

```
sorted(apples.split(','), key=lambda x: -float(x.split(':')[1]))

['Fuji:8',
 'Honeycrisp:7.5',
 'Ambrosia:7',
 'Gala:6',
 'Red Delicious:5',
 'McIntosh:3',
 'Granny Smith:1']
```

---

The first necessary step is to `split` the above string into a list which will be fed to `sorted`:

```
print(apples.split(','))
# ['McIntosh:3', 'Red Delicious:5', 'Fuji:8', 'Gala:6', 'Ambrosia:7', 
#   'Honeycrisp:7.5', 'Granny Smith:1']
```

Then the above key, `lambda x: -float(x.split(':')[1])` will be splitting the inner strings by `':'`, then indexing on the second element in the resulting list and casting to float. By taking the negative the ordering will be descending.